# Sort an array multidimensional after a value of key PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a array ,this one, which i what to sort after value of the key `sum`

```
Array
(
[anexus] => Array
    (
        [nr000000] => Array
            (
                [January2015] => Array
                    (
                        [nTurn] => 0.0000
                        [nCalls] => 0
                        [nMin] => 0
                        [c] =>l
                    )

                [sum] => 0
                [February2015] => Array
                    (
                        [nTurn] => 0.0000
                        [nCalls] => 0
                        [nMin] => 0
                        [c] => ch
                    )

                [March2015] => Array
                    (
                        [nTurn] => 0.0000
                        [nCalls] => 0
                        [nMin] => 0
                        [c] => 
                    )


            )

        [nrh00789] => Array
            (
                [January2015] => Array
                    (
                        [nTurn] => 0.0000
                        [nCalls] => 0
                        [nMin] => 0
                        [c] => 
                    )

                [sum] => 0
                [February2015] => Array
                    (
                        [nTurn] => 0.0000
                        [nCalls] => 0
                        [nMin] => 0
                        [c] => ch
                    )

                [March2015] => Array
                    (
                        [nTurn] => 0.0000
                        [nCalls] => 0
                        [nMin] => 0
                        [c] => ch
                    )




            )

    )

[deluxe] => Array
    (
        [nr00078] => Array
            (
                [January2015] => Array
                    (
                        [nTurn] => 0.0000
                        [nCalls] => 0
                        [nMin] => 0
                        [c] => at
                    )

                [sum] => 21
                [February2015] => Array
                    (
                        [nTurn] => 0.0000
                        [nCalls] => 0
                        [nMin] => 0
                        [c] => at
                    )

                [March2015] => Array
                    (
                        [nTurn] => 0.0000
                        [nCalls] => 0
                        [nMin] => 0
                        [c] =>p
                    )



            )

        [nr000800] => Array
            (
                [January2015] => Array
                    (
                        [nTurn] => 0.0000
                        [nCalls] => 0
                        [nMin] => 0
                        [c] => de
                    )

                [sum] => 71
                [February2015] => Array
                    (
                        [nTurn] => 0.0000
                        [nCalls] => 0
                        [nMin] => 0
                        [c] => de
                    )

                [March2015] => Array
                    (
                        [nTurn] => 0.0000
                        [nCalls] => 0
                        [nMin] => 0
                        [c] => de
                    )





            )
```

This is a part of array which I what to sort after the key `sum`

Comment: Post your attempts what you have tried so far along with expected output

Comment: You should use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function to do a custom sort.

Comment: I tried with a function for compare but isn't working, 
I want for example [anexus]=>[nr000000]=>sum=0 to be last followed by [[nr000000]]=> sum[0] and the first element in array to be [deluxe]= > [nr000800] =>sum=71  and the second to be  [deluxe]= > [nr00078] =>sum=21

Answer (score 0):

Just use **array_shift()**, look at [http://php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and sort using whatever function you want, then you can add "sum" back using **array_unshift()**, look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php).